# Google Cloud: our instance is running but we are not able to access the site via external IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitnami

We have 4 instances running on Google Cloud and only 1 of them is not accessible. When I view the instance, everything appears to be fine. I ran the Bitnami support tool and it returned the following issues:

? Apache: Found possible issues
? Connectivity: Found possible issues
? Php: Found possible issues
https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/troubleshooting/debug-errors-apache/
https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/moodle/troubleshooting/deny-connections-bots-apache/
https://docs.bitnami.com/general/faq/administration/use-firewall/
https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/configuration/configure-phpfpm-processes/

I looked through each case but it doesn't appear that any of those issues would keep the site from coming up. Can someone give me a suggestion to help with this problem?

Comment: What is the external IP? What is the hostname of the site?

Comment: Including links for additional reference is good. Creating a question with only links is bad. Links sometimes are edited, moved, deleted, etc rendering your question useless in the future. In your question, show the details necessary to understand the problem with error messages, test results, etc. Your question should be self-contained without requiring links to external resources.

Comment: Bitnami developer here. This question was also opened in our community forum, where we found some issues related to the WordPress theme in Apache logs, but your website seemed to work properly. Did you have any chance to check the theme errors? https://community.bitnami.com/t/our-cloud-instance-is-running-but-site-is-down/98558

Answer (score 0):

For your comments, if your VM is running healthy and if the information on the links that you mentioned does not apply to your case, maybe you can check if the [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) that you are using could be blocking some traffic intended for your non-accessible VM.

Have you checked if you have internet access from the VM?
Are TCP/IP settings correctly configured into that VM?
Are the [routing paths](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#listing-routes-vm) correctly set up for that VM?